# i have a different output idea for the code

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

i have a question that tells me to write the output of the following program :

```
cont = 0; int p[2];

void* f1() {    
    while(!cont){} 
    printf("%d ", close(p[0])); return NULL; 
}

int main() { 
    pthread_t t1;

    pipe(p); 
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,f1,NULL);
    fork(); 
    printf("%d ", close(p[0]));
    cont = 1;   
    pthread_join(t1,NULL); 

    return 0;
}
```

the answer is 2 options : either 0 -1 0  or 0 0 -1

i think the answer is 0 -1 0 -1 , since everything is duplicated using fork()
this means that the parent will call close(p[0]) and print 0 and then its duplication of the thread will call close(p[0]) but print -1 , and the same happens with the child. so overall 0 -1 0 -1 , what did i do wrong ?

Comment: Did you run it to see what you get?

Comment: You should read up on how fork and threads interact...

Comment: "*its duplication of the thread*". `fork` does not result in all the parent process threads being run in the child process. From the [fork manual](https://manpages.org/fork): "*A process shall be created with a single thread*"

Comment: What a terrible question.  I suppose it is intended at least in part to probe your understanding of the point that @kaylum raised, but the program has a data race involving `cont`, and therefore its behavior is undefined.

Comment: Additionally, even if the data race were fixed (by making `cont` atomic, for instance), it is unspecified in what relative order the outputs from the two resulting processes will be written.  Either "0 0 -1" could be produced (two ways) or 0 -1 0 could be produced.

Comment: (To be clear: I am primarily criticizing the question posed to you, not the one you have posed to us.)

Comment: regrding: `while(!cont){} `   tjhis produced a loop that will never exit so the following call to printf(0 and close() will never be executed

Comment: rhis `fork(); 
    printf("%d ", close(p[0]));
    cont = 1;   
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);` is being executed in both the parent and the child process  which process executes a `printf()` first is totally arbitrary

Answer (score 0):

Here are good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080811/what-happens-to-other-threads-when-one-thread-forks) about what happens when a process using `pthread`  uses `fork`.
This should explain why only 3 outputs are displayed from `printf`s.