# Is fork process an example of Multi threading in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, posix

I have heard that programming languages like java have concept of multi threading .When i studied fork process in c language , i thought if it  is an example of multi threading .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between fork and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483041/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-thread)

Comment: Why did you delete your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913216/given-n-integers-in-a-round-fashion-how-to-choose-them-in-pairs-to-minimise-new) (and my answer with it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't. C doesn't even know `fork()`, but I assume you're talking about the POSIX function `fork()`. This creates a new process, which runs completely isolated (with a few exceptions like it can inherit open file descriptors) from the parent process.

For threading in C, have a look at the [thread functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) in C11. Unfortunately, the support for these isn't very widespread, but there's also the POSIX threading interface [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

Answer (score 1):

`fork` can be used to emulate threads (and it is certainly a way to introduce parallelism into a computation), but far fewer resources are shared with the parent process.  On many systems, it is possible to share part of the address space by creating a `MAP_SHARED` mapping prior to forking, but apart from that, both processes are separate.  Even file descriptors are only inherited—if you close them or open new ones, the other process is not affected by that.